# Copying Data from CSV to Excel Error

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am getting an error 438 on the Activate step. I had originally tried to copy/paste using a value=value. The copy worked, but the paste did not. Then I tried a copy/paste, then I added in the activation.

Can I do this? Or do I need to save the file as an XLS before copying data from it? It is preferable to only have the CSV, but I can create and then delete the XLS file if necessary.

```
Sub Update_QSPI_Data()

Dim wbDT As Workbook
Dim wbQSPI As Workbook
Dim wsExport As Worksheet
Dim wsQSPI As Worksheet


Set wbDT = Workbooks("File the Macro is Run from/where I want the new data")
Set wsExport = wbDT.Worksheets("Tab I want the data on")

'First we want to clear the tab  of all hidden columns, formatting, and data.

'If there is a hidden cell then unhide all the columns. Prevents an error in the instance that
'no columns are hidden

Dim j As Long 'Index for unhiding columns
For j = 1 To 53
7 If wsExport.Cells(1, j).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
    wsExport.Cells(1, j).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
Next j

'This is the equivalent of "Clear All" in the dropdown menu

wsExport.Range("A:BA").Clear

'Now we want to open up the new QSPI Data

'Workbooks.Open("Path")
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Folders\Desktop\CSV_FILE.csv"), Local:=True 

Set wbQSPI = Workbooks("CSV_FILE")
Set wsQSPI = wbQSPI.Sheets(1) 
Dim lRow As Long 'Last Row of Data

lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row


'copy the data
wbQSPI.wsQSPI.Activate
wbQSPI.wsQSPI.Range("A1:AL" & lRow).Select
Selection.Copy
wbDT.wsExport.Activate
wbDT.wsExport.Range("A1:AL" & lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Comment: remove the workbook reference it is already part of the worksheet variable: `wsQSPI.Activate`.  And remove  all the Activate and select: `wsQSPI.Range("A1:AL" & lRow).Copy wsExport.Range("A1:AL" & lRow)`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much!